# Use emoji inside terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, fonts, emoji

OS X has emoji support inside terminal, and I'm a little jelly.

[Emoji One Color SVGinOT Font](https://github.com/eosrei/emojione-color-font) brings emoji support to Ubuntu, but at the moment the terminal will only render monochrome emojis.

Is there a way to get these color beauties in gnome terminal?

Comment: No, the terminal emulation widget VTE behind gnome-terminal (and many other emulators) does not support this.

Comment: It's okay, I don't even know why I want this.

Comment: You're a little jelly?

Comment: You can use [this _test-drive_](https://hellricer.github.io/2019/10/05/test-drive-your-terminal.html) (also [here](https://gist.github.com/hellricer/e514d9615d02838244d8de74d0ab18b3#file-terminal-testdrive-sh)). Some terminal emulators don't support bitmap emojis

Answer (score 41):

I'm the creator of that font.

Sorry, there is not way to see SVGinOT (SVG-in-OpenType) color fonts in anything other than Gecko-based applications such as Firefox and Thunderbird right now. I made these fonts to solve the "chicken or the egg" problem: there were no color fonts and so no reason to support them. Now there are color fonts... Next steps: Probably a feature request on Launchpad?

Answer (score 38):

Our wait is finally over guys!
Emojis are supported by default inside terminal, from Ubuntu 18 on.

Check your version with:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (development branch)
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

---

Not strictly related, but here is a screenshot of how it plays with https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-emojify, npm package that uses emojis for automation messages:

[image: Ubuntu terminal executing Gulp command, with a waiting message displaying a Beer and a Coffee emoji]

(You may have to `sudo apt install fonts-emojione`)

Comment: This is a scattershot and unclear answer.

Comment: How version number (which introduces feature OP is asking) can be unclear?  @Lexible

Comment: When one has to read it 2-3 times to understand what the answer means & suggests, that's unclear. Too much unnecessary overhead info & code. I've suggested some edits to make it clearer.

Answer (score 10):

In GNOME Terminal (it also works in any other application), use the following keyboard shortcut:

1. Hit <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>, then press <kbd>Space</kbd>.
2. You should see the *Emoji Choice* popup where you can select your unicode character.

[image: Emoji Choice on GNOME Terminal, Animals & Nature, Unicode special characters]

Tested on Ubuntu Cosmic (18.10).

Comment: I came here looking for a different thing, but I just discovered this and it's awesome, thanks!

Comment: Nope. This does not work as you describe in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Nor in 22.10.  Apparently it stopped working at some point.  :(

Answer (score 7):

Color Emojis are not currently supported. Apparently there is a patched WIP version of `libcairo` that allows rendering colored emojis but it isn't stable yet.

https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-emoji/issues/36#issuecomment-168209204

Support for this will likely come down to something that needs to be implemented on a per-app or per-UI-lib (GTK, Qt etc) basis so it may take a while for some apps to support it even once the underlying OS libraries do.

**UPDATE:**
The `libcairo` patch has made it's way into mainstream repositories for most distros, they should now work natively by default if you have an up-to-date install, but you may need to [modify your fontconfig](https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-emoji/issues/36#issuecomment-343655365) to actually use them.

Answer (score 5):

In your bashrc script...

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

You can define an array of emoticons

```
EMOJIS=(                            )
```

then if you have too much time on your hands, write a function which returns a random moj.

```
RANDOM_EMOJI() {
  SELECTED_EMOJI=${EMOJIS[$RANDOM % ${#EMOJIS[@]}]};
  echo $SELECTED_EMOJI;
}
EMJ() {
  emj
}
```