# How can I add emojis to oh-my-zsh

Tags: command-line, themes

I use Ubuntu 16.04. I installed [terminator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/terminator/), [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/), [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) and [agnoster](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes#agnoster) theme. My current terminal look like this

[image]

I can any symbol from awesome fonts to my terminal. But **how can I add image in my terminal?**, same as beautiful terminal in [heroku website](https://www.heroku.com/python#see-it-in-action)

[image]

Comment: I guess they are emojis, not images ! And knowing the codes of emojis, it might be simple.

Comment: @luv.preet: On top of the code points you also need the right font that contains the desired glyphs.

Comment: @luv.preet, I find out that there is a color emoji font in linux https://github.com/eosrei/EmojiOne-Color-Font. But it's not supported in terminal yet https://askubuntu.com/a/784753/727058. Color emoji only works in mac http://osxdaily.com/2013/04/08/add-emoji-command-line-bash-prompt/, right?