# Cannot use emoji in terminal and on kate kubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, emoji

I have Kubuntu 22.04 installed and I cannot use emoji in terminal and Kate application.
I found some articles online:

1. [Use emoji inside terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781851/use-emoji-inside-terminal)
2. [Cannot Use Emoji within Browsers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301967/cannot-use-emoji-within-browsers)

Neither does not work for me. I need some help, please.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Nmath Before I have upgraded to Kubuntu 22.04.even on 21.10 version i had this issue.

Comment: maybe i am missing package or something?

Comment: @Nmath i dont believe so. How can i find out?

Answer (score 2):

NVM it works.

I used this command

`sudo apt install kubuntu-Desktop`

There were several packages that need to be installed. Once installed, I reboot my PC. Now, it works!

[image]

[image]